# How to inactive other dropdown while I am clicking another one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

[![

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
  <!-- for every dropdown, start here -->
  <button class="dropdown-btn" style="width: 100%;">Admin 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="/java.html">Admin Profile</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Change Password</a>
  </div>
  <!-- End here -->
  <button class="dropdown-btn" style="width: 100%;">Doctors 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="/java.html">Doctors List</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Doctors Appointments</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Doctors Requests</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Add a Doctor</a>
  </div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn" style="width: 100%;">Patients 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="/java.html">Patient List</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Patients Appointments</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Patient Requests</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Add a Patient</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZjTs.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZjTs.jpg)Here I wanted to inactive toggle like if I click on doctors and then click to admin, doctor's toggle will be converted to inactive automatically . I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: please provide more details of your problem

Comment: Yeah I have added a picture also

Comment: What disables a list? A classse? The image for example shows some lists that are not being displayed, what makes them to be displayed or not?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use jQuery to listen `dropdown-btn` event. Activate all buttons and disable the clicked button.

Like this code:

```js
$('.dropdown-btn').on('click', function(){
        $(".dropdown-btn").attr("disabled", false);
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
  <!-- for every dropdown, start here -->
  <button class="dropdown-btn" style="width: 100%;">Admin 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="/java.html">Admin Profile</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Change Password</a>
  </div>
  <!-- End here -->
  <button class="dropdown-btn" style="width: 100%;">Doctors 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="/java.html">Doctors List</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Doctors Appointments</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Doctors Requests</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Add a Doctor</a>
  </div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn" style="width: 100%;">Patients 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="/java.html">Patient List</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Patients Appointments</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Patient Requests</a>
    <a href="/cSharp.html">Add a Patient</a>
  </div>
</div>
```